# Stretching a panel to fill the whole window as opposed to just a corner

Tags: python, wxpython

When I run my wxPython application (code below), all the widgets seem to be clumped together in the upper left portion of the window. I want it so that the window is exactly the same size as the sizer but I can't seem to get exactly that.

This is what I'm getting:

[image: What I'm getting, but not what I want]

And this is the effect I want, minus the crappy gray background:

[image: What I want, but its buggy]

Is there any way to stretch the parent panel so that it fills the whole window? Removing the panel seems to give me exactly what I want, but without it the whole window turns a drab, dark gray color and it looks unnatural from an aesthetic standpoint, so I'd like to keep it if possible.

According to wx.version() I'm using version 3.0.0.0 msw (classic), on Python 2.7.6.

```
class MyMenu(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        super(MyMenu, self).__init__(parent, id, title)

        valid_targets = ["jpg", "gif", "pcx", 
            "msp", "png", "ppm", "tiff"]

        # Cheap Image Converter v .1
        # File to convert: [            ] <Select File>
        # Convert to: [.jpg]v 
        # [CONVERT]

        self.convert_target = None
        self.raw_file = []
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        # all elements will be declared in the order in which
        # they appear, top to bottom, left to right.
        self.intro_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "Image Converter v 0.1")

        # Load files button and binding
        self.file_convert_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1,
            "Select a file to convert.")
        self.file_text_box = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1,
            "Select a file!", style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.load_file_button = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Load Files")
        self.load_file_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SelectFileDialog)

        # Conversion type selection box and label
        self.choice_list_desc = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1,
            "Select format to convert to: ")
        self.choice_list = wx.Choice(self.panel, -1,
            choices=valid_targets)
        self.choice_list.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, 
            self.SelectFromChoice)

        # Convert button!
        self.go_button = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Convert!")
        self.go_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.PerformConversion)

        # sizers!
        self.master_container = wx.GridBagSizer(4, 3)

        self.master_container.Add(self.intro_text, (0,0), (1,3), wx.EXPAND)

        self.master_container.Add(self.file_convert_text, (1,0), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        self.master_container.Add(self.file_text_box, (1,1), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.master_container.Add(self.load_file_button, (1,2), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.master_container.Add(self.choice_list_desc, (2,0), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND)
        self.master_container.Add(self.choice_list, (2,1), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND)

        self.master_container.Add(self.go_button, (3,0), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.master_container)
        self.Centre()
# callbacks removed for brevity.
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyMenu(None, -1, 'Python Bulk Image Converter')
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: I'm not seeing what you are. When I use `self` instead of the panel, the widgets are in the exact same locations as they are with the panel as their parent. Can you post a picture of what you want in addition to what you don't? Also which wxPython version are you using?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll I've updated the post with a second picture, and version info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of confusing in wxPython. Personally, I find the `Fit` and the `SetSizerAndFit` methods very annoying and not very useful. However, since this is what you want, the way to do it is to change the following line in your code:

```
self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.master_container)
```

to this:

```
self.panel.SetSizer(self.master_container)
self.master_container.Fit(self)
```

Here's the full code (note I commented out all event bindings since those methods weren't present in your example):

```
import wx

class MyMenu(wx.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, id, title):
        super(MyMenu, self).__init__(parent, id, title)

        valid_targets = ["jpg", "gif", "pcx", 
            "msp", "png", "ppm", "tiff"]

        # Cheap Image Converter v .1
        # File to convert: [            ] <Select File>
        # Convert to: [.jpg]v 
        # [CONVERT]

        self.convert_target = None
        self.raw_file = []
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)

        # all elements will be declared in the order in which
        # they appear, top to bottom, left to right.
        self.intro_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1, "Image Converter v 0.1")

        # Load files button and binding
        self.file_convert_text = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1,
            "Select a file to convert.")
        self.file_text_box = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, -1,
            "Select a file!", style=wx.TE_READONLY)
        self.load_file_button = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Load Files")
        #self.load_file_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.SelectFileDialog)

        # Conversion type selection box and label
        self.choice_list_desc = wx.StaticText(self.panel, -1,
            "Select format to convert to: ")
        self.choice_list = wx.Choice(self.panel, -1,
            choices=valid_targets)
        #self.choice_list.Bind(wx.EVT_CHOICE, 
            #self.SelectFromChoice)

        # Convert button!
        self.go_button = wx.Button(self.panel, -1, "Convert!")
        #self.go_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.PerformConversion)

        # sizers!
        self.master_container = wx.GridBagSizer(4, 3)

        self.master_container.Add(self.intro_text, (0,0), (1,3), wx.EXPAND)

        self.master_container.Add(self.file_convert_text, (1,0), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_RIGHT)
        self.master_container.Add(self.file_text_box, (1,1), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.master_container.Add(self.load_file_button, (1,2), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.master_container.Add(self.choice_list_desc, (2,0), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND)
        self.master_container.Add(self.choice_list, (2,1), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND)

        self.master_container.Add(self.go_button, (3,0), wx.DefaultSpan, wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.Layout()
        self.panel.SetSizer(self.master_container)
        self.master_container.Fit(self)

        self.Centre()

# callbacks removed for brevity.
class MyApp(wx.App):
    def OnInit(self):
        frame = MyMenu(None, -1, 'Python Bulk Image Converter')
        frame.Show(True)
        return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = MyApp(0)
    app.MainLoop()
```

This code was tested on Xubuntu 14.04, wxPython 2.8.12.1 with Python 2.7